# Django Model not Defined in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that I'm trying to provide an ID and have it return records from a mysql database based on that ID.

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class RateskioskMain(models.Model):
    EID = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, default=0,)
    ETISmUnits = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    ETISmHours = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)
```

It created a table in my database called rateskiosk_rateskioskmain.

Here's my views.py:

```
def homepage_view(request):
    result_obj = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        eid = request.POST.get('eid')
        result_count = RateskioskMain.objects.filter(EID=int(eid)).count()
        if result_count > 0:
            result_obj = RateskioskMain.objects.get(EID=eid)
    return render(request, 'ratekiosk/homepage.html', {'result_obj': result_obj})
```

But then when I try to run it, I get:

```
Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'RakesKioskMain' is not defined
```

Not sure what I'm missing, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you import your model in views.py?

Comment: `RakesKioskMain` has an upper case `K` but your class has a lower case `k` in `kiosk`. Could this be an issue? You can also try `from models import RateskioskMain` in your "views.py"

Comment: Your `views.py` has no `import` statements at all.

Comment: I had import statements, just didn't actually import my model. Stupid mistake. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import RakesKioskMain into your views.py. Do:

```
from *App*.models import RakesKiosMain
```